# How to update ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

First: what's the difference between `gs` and `ghostscript`?

```
thiago@vaio:~$ gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

thiago@vaio:~$ ghostscript -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.04 (2011-08-05)
Copyright (C) 2011 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

I've just compiled and installed `ghostscript-9.06.tar`. But I still have some errors when I try to open my `.dvi` files with `xdvi`, for example: `xdvik: read_from_gs: Connection reset by peer.`

Well, I'd like to remove everything about old `gs/ghostscript` and install the newest version.

Thanks for helping.

**edit:** the result of these 2 commands:

```
thiago@vaio:/usr/bin$ gs
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GS>^C
thiago@vaio:/usr/bin$ ghostscript 
GPL Ghostscript 9.04 (2011-08-05)
Copyright (C) 2011 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GS>^C
thiago@vaio:/usr/bin$
```

The second one opens a window also.

Comment: On my system `ghostscript` is a symbolic link to `gs`, therefore it's the same. Apparently you have different versions installed and `gs` links to the the current one.

Comment: Why do you need to compile the program manually from sources? Can't you use your distribution package manager?

Comment: @gorkypl, I only find 9.04 on synaptic. But there is the 9.06 version. http://www.ghostscript.com/download/

Comment: IMO unless there are features or bug-fixes in 9.06 that you absolutely require now, you're better off waiting until your distro packages it.

Comment: @CraigSanders, yes, I agree now. Somebody ask me to update my I agree that it is better to maintain. How to remove 9.06? I am getting error qhen I open the `.dvi` file from texstudio: `Process started: xdvi "Fastex-temp."dvi xdvik: read_from_gs: Connection closed by other peer` and with 9.04 I didn't have this error.

Comment: to uninstall, hopefully the Makefile has an uninstall target.  if not, try `make -n install`, and make a note of all the files it would have installed. then delete them. undo anything else relevant the install target did.  hope you get it all.  welcome to the joys of pre-package-manager *nix.

Comment: @CraigSanders, I deleted its folders. I have `whereis gs
gs: /usr/bin/gs /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/share/man/man1/gs.1.gz` but when I run `gs` it still shows `GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)`. I don't know how to go back to the old version.